# webpack --watch does not want to process react component inside my index.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm an old hat coder but I'm new to react, and it looks like I need another pair of eyeballs.  I'm trying to setup a very basic React app from scratch (for practice) and it fires up fine, but when I try to run webpack --watch it's giving me the following error:

## Here's the error I'm getting:

```
    ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import App from "./components/App.js";
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
|
```

## Here's my webpack.dev.config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist"),
        filename: "index_bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

## Here's my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "react-boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "watch": "webpack --watch --open",
        "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --mode development --config ./webpack.dev.config.js",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "webpack": "^4.29.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.3"
    }
}
```

## Here's my .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

## And finally... my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./components/App.js";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twALJ.jpg)

This ought to be pretty straight-forward but I guess I'm just not seeing something.  I'd appreciate any help!!

Comment: Does it work if you give `presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]` to the `babel-loader` options directly in the Webpack config instead? It might be that it's not picking up `.babelrc` correctly.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this? I am experiencing the same issue...

Comment: I think so, but it's been so long since I looked at that one that I don't remember what my solution was, but my guess is that I misspelled something, or had a typo.  Usually it's something stupid like that.